# Android MSAL Login failed incase if My app is already Auto enrollment successful using Company portal app

Tags: azure-ad-msal, adal, intune, microsoft-graph-intune, azure-android-sdk

We are migrating our authentication of Azure from ADAL to MSAL. Our app support Intune feature.

We are facing login failure during MSAL login, if the app is already automatically enrolled using Company portal app or open-in work flow from the other apps is already Intune Enrollment successfully completed.

We are getting **MsalException** as **unknown_error**. Exception screenshot below
[image]

I am expecting there could be some workaround for user to do login and get a accessToken and IdToken through MSAL even MAMErollment is completed for the app OR is there a way to block Auto enrollment through Company portal app.

```
publicClientApplication.acquireToken(
                    new AcquireTokenParameters.Builder().startAuthorizationFromActivity(mActivity)
                            .withScopes(Collections.singletonList(azureInfoOnInterActiveLogin.getResourceUri().concat("/.default")))
                            .withCallback(authenticationCallback)
                            .withPrompt(Prompt.WHEN_REQUIRED)
                            .withLoginHint("xxxx@xx.com")
                            .build()
            );
```

**Note:** With our legacy implementation of ADAL, acquireToken request is getting successful & able to get acessToken and idToken even the app is already automatically enrolled using Company portal. This is came up on MSAL only. Not on ADAL.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug. [`isFullBrowser(final ResolveInfo resolveInfo)`](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-common-for-android/blob/b89d190a516e5c0ea4b6109dcd2561c67113e17b/common/src/main/java/com/microsoft/identity/common/internal/ui/browser/BrowserSelector.java#L174) is getting a null value which is not expected. Ensure you're using the latest version of the library. If the problem persists, please open a [Github issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug_report.md&title=) and share it's URL.

Comment: yes, correct. I am getting exception from (!resolveInfo.filter.hasAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)

Comment: @Shanmugapriyan were you able to fix this issue? If yes, can you please tell?

Comment: @XeshanJ No, this issue not fixed.

Comment: I am able to fix it by setting "authorization_user_agent" : "WEBVIEW"